# Is JSP supposed to have embedded HTML?

Tags: jsp

I'm learning about JSP, old yes, but I'm using it to at least be familiar with it, so I can move on to Spring, Spring MVC, etc.

Is JSP supposed to be loaded with embedded HTML?  It reminds me of Classic ASP.  Snippet taken from a JSP book.

```
                    writer.println("<tr>");
                    writer.println("<td>" + quantity + "</td>");
                    writer.println("<td>" + product.getName()
                            + "</td>");
                    writer.println("<td>"
                            + currencyFormat.format(price)
                            + "</td>");
                    double subtotal = price * quantity;

                    writer.println("<td>"
                            + currencyFormat.format(subtotal)
                            + "</td>");
                    total += subtotal;
                    writer.println("</tr>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the languages separate helps define their roles (view and presentation vs data):

```
<tr>
    <td><%= quantity %></td>
</tr>
```

Or even better, using JSTL instead of scriptlets (which for the most part should be considered deprecated):

```
<tr>
    <td><c:out value="${quantity}" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can embed HTML in the JSP code like that or you can output HTML using inline JSP like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>First JSP</title></head>
<body>
  <%
    double num = Math.random();
    if (num > 0.95) {
  %>
      <h2>You'll have a luck day!</h2><p>(<%= num %>)</p>
  <%
    } else {
  %>
      <h2>Well, life goes on ... </h2><p>(<%= num %>)</p>
  <%
    }
  %>
  <a href="<%= request.getRequestURI() %>"><h3>Try Again</h3></a>
</body>
</html>
```

([Example code source.](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JSPByExample.html))

Yes, it looks like ASP, PHP, ColdFusion and pretty much other any scripting language.

Comment: Please, don't suggest using scriptlets. Scriptlets should not be used anymore. And that's true for more than 10 years.